# psi digamma function

Tags: digamma-function

Is well known that 
$$\psi(x)-\psi(-x)=-\pi \cot(\pi x) - \frac{1}{x}.$$
I am wondering if a similar property holds for the following function,
$$D_{\beta,\gamma}(x) = \psi(\beta x)-\psi(-\gamma x),\ \beta,\gamma \in {\mathbb{Z}_{>0}},$$
i.e. if 
$D_{\beta,\gamma}(x) =\text{a periodic function} + O\Big(\frac{1}{x}\Big)?$
Any ideas?

## Edit.

It may be useful the following,

1. $D_{\beta,\gamma}(x)=(\beta+\gamma)x\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{(n+x\beta)(n-\gamma x)}.$
2. $\beta\not= \gamma$ since if $\beta=\gamma$ the function is periodic.
3. [checked experimentaly] It seems that $D_{\beta,\gamma}(x+T)\approx D_{\beta,\gamma}(x)$ for large x and $T=\beta+\gamma.$

Comment: It follows directly from $\Gamma(s+1) = s \Gamma(s)$ that $\psi(s)-\psi(1-s)$ is periodic. What do you get for your function ?

Comment: This proves $\psi(x)-\psi(-x)=-\pi \cot(\pi x) -1/x.$ Also proves that $D_{b,b}(x)$ is of the same form. Can't say anything for $D_{\beta,\gamma}(x).$

Comment: $\psi(x)-\psi(1-x)=-\pi \cot(\pi x)$ is more difficult than just saying $\psi(x)-\psi(1-x)$ is periodic and it doesn't follow only from $\Gamma(x+1) = x\Gamma(x), \psi(x) = \Gamma'(x)/\Gamma(x)$

Comment: true, you need also cosecant formula of gamma function

Comment: I am not sure that $D_{\beta,\gamma}(x)$ is periodic, do you have a proof based on gamma properties?

Comment: It is not ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: sorry I meant $\psi(\beta x)-\psi(1-\gamma x)$ (and not $D_{\beta,\gamma}(x).$) Because in your first comment I understood that, based on gamma properties you can prove that $\psi(\beta x)-\psi(1-\gamma x)$ is periodic, as in the case of $\psi(x)-\psi(1-x).$

Answer (score 1):

By setting $z=-\gamma x$ in the reflection formula $\psi(z) - \psi(1-z) = -\pi \cot(\pi z)$ we get
$$\psi(-\gamma x) - \psi(1+\gamma x) = \pi \cot(\pi \gamma x).$$
So $$D_{\beta,\gamma}(x) = \psi(\beta x) - \psi(1+\gamma x) - \pi \cot(\pi \gamma x). $$
From the well know relation
$$\psi(z) - \ln{z} = -\frac{1}{2z}+O(\frac{1}{z^2})$$
we get 
$$D_{\beta,\gamma}(x) = [\psi(\beta x) - \ln(\beta x)] - [\psi((1+\gamma x) - \ln(1+\gamma x)] +$$
$$ \ln{(\frac{\beta x}{1+\gamma x})} - \pi \cot(\pi \gamma x)=$$
$$\ln(\frac{\beta}{\gamma})-\pi\cot(\pi\gamma x)+O(\frac{1}{x}).$$ 
So, indeed $D_{\beta,\gamma}(x)$ for large $x$ is a sum of a periodic function with period 1 and a term $O(1/x).$